# Cannot resolve the method SpringSecurity

Tags: spring-security, jhipster

I'm developing a jhipster application, and I'm trying to show for every user of my application only the entity that he created: I added this code to the?

PianoResourceIntTest.java:

```java
@Test
@Transactional
public void getAllPianos() throws Exception {
    // Initialize the database

    restPianoMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecurity()).build();
    // pianoRepository.saveAndFlush(piano);
    piano.setUser(userRepository.findOneByLogin("user").get());
    pianoRepository.saveAndFlush(piano);

    // Get all the pianos
    //restPianoMockMvc.perform(get("/api/pianos?sort=id,desc").with(user("user")))
    restPianoMockMvc.perform(get("/api/pianos?sort=id,desc").with(user("user"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].id").value(hasItem(piano.getId().intValue())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].name").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_NAME.toString())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].date").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_DATE.toString())));
}
```

But I'm getting two errors :

```
Cannot resolve the method SpringSecurity
Cannot resolve the symbol user
```

I dont know how to deal with this problem and how to resolve the problem.

Comment: I answered but your question is really bad. You did not give enough details : what kind of error (runtime or compilation). your code extract did not include  important parts like the imports or the class definition to see if it extended another class. Also, you're posting often, so please improve the quality of your questions

Comment: can you please add more details to your question (just edit it)? What could be useful to identify the problem are the Spring configuration and the dependencies of the projects (the POM file, if you're using Maven)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the errors are compilation errors not runtime errors.

user() is a static method in class SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors so you add a static import to it.

Same thing for springSecurity() which is a static method in class SecurityMockMvcConfigurers

Check the [Spring Security doc about Spring MVC test integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html#running-as-a-user-in-spring-mvc-test-with-annotations)

Comment: I'm so sorry but I'm really a beginner ,yes this is a compilation error: I add
<spring-security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring-security.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
 to my pom.xml file and when I'm trying to make a static import : " import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.*; " I have an error : "test cannot be resolved" I don't know why?

Comment: it's nearly impossible to help you, you 're not giving enough information. you should post a gist (https://gist.github.com/) to your pom.xml and test class. Is maven able to resolve your dependencies?